# How to load data automatically in jtable from mysql database without insert before (just load data) every one seconds?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

hello I want to ask how to load data to Jtable from mysql database, in the past I've successfully do that after insert data but now I want to Try load them without  insert data or push button anything. the data have done inserted by php system, now I want to make java interface to make the desktop interface. can it works like ajax  load in php?? I'm new in java thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create JDBC connection with database to fetch data from database.
To make a JDBC connection you need to follow these steps:

1. Download `mysqlconnector.jar` and 
   go to `jre/lib/ext` folder and paste the jar file here.
2. Set classpath:-

   Open a command prompt and write:

   ```
   C:>set classpath=c:\folder\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;.;
   ```

   It will set a temporary classpath.
3. To create connection to database the code is :-

   ```
   import java.sql.*;

   class MysqlCon {  
     public static void main(String args[]) {  
       try {  
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( 
           "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb","root","root");  

         //here testdb is database name, root is username and password  

         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
         while(rs.next())  
           System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
         con.close();  
       } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
       }  
     }  
   }
   ```

   Or you can get reference from: https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

Comment: ok it works, I mean how to run a table function in a few seconds?

Comment: Which table you are using? If then table is in html or if you are using jquery then you can use jquery datatable to print your data in front end. If you are satisfied with my answer then give up a vote to me. Thanks